# Perform a search on google chrome using ADB

Tags: android, shell, adb

I'm setting up a python script for doing some tests on android phones.

I can actually launch a new chrome tab on my phone with ADB:

`shell am start -n com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity -d "about:newtab" --activity-clear-task`

I can't figure out the way I could perform a search on chrome with the search provider included in.

Comment: Google search:
`adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity -d "google.com/search?q=how%20can%20I%20do%20it?" --activity-clear-task`

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I would like to perform a search with the default search provider of chrome. I don't know if i'm clear, but imagine the user changed his settings, and now search with Yahoo. Is there a way via ADB to only send the command 'search this', without a full google/yahoo link ?

Answer (score 0):

The suggested command by @oss does not care about user settings/defaults , it only require that google chrome is installed!

You may need to create a function like this:

```
function adbgs () { 
    local str="${*}";
    adb shell am start -n com.android.chrome/org.chromium.chrome.browser.ChromeTabbedActivity -d "google.com/search?q=${str// /+}" --activity-clear-task
}
adbgs how to do stuff;
```

Or if you want search using default browser :

```
function adburlopen () { 
    adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "${1}"
}
# google
function adbgs () { 
    local str="${*}";
    adburlopen "https://www.google.com/search?q=${str// /+}";
}
# yahoo
function adbys () { 
    local str="${*}";
    adburlopen "https://sg.search.yahoo.com/search?q=${str// /+}";
}
```